# How to get throughput and response time in Jmeter in Non GUI mode

Tags: html, server, jmeter, jmx

Actually I don't want to generate HTML file, it is unable to parse for rsp and tsp. I am using Jmeter on server and using from non GUI mode. I normally come across to run many different threads with more than 1 sampler requests. So , I need to get the response time and throughput for those threads on a quick and easy basis.
JTL result and csv file is giving rsp only. I need perfect solution which provides my solution.
even if there is a way to generate a csv file containing results of RSP and TSP which I need, will be fine for me.

** also I cant load the jtl file on jmeter on my system to check results manually.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be going for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which can generate a CSV form of the [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener out of the .jtl results file, you will need to execute a command like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv report.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Just replace `result.jtl` with your .jtl results file name and the tool will create the Aggregate Report for you,

You can install this `JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool` along with 
[Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Command Line Tool Plugins Manager]

Comment: Agregate report is nt giving everything that we see in GUI mode. Throughput and response time is still not showing. How could I get only Throughput response time in a seprate file or csv,

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Generate CSV including Throughput and Responsetime
-1- Need to install JMeter Plugin Manager - Download the jar file "jmeter-plugins-manager-1.1.jar" - Place it in lib/ext
-2- Install command-line graph plotting tool using JMeter Plugin Manager option in "Options"
-3- Install jpgc-synthesis for AggregateReport using JMeter Plugin Mangager
-4- And use the following command

> java -jar C:\Performance\apache-jmeter-3.3\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl testJmeter3.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport